# Detail disclosure send data from custom annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have pins showing on a map with data from a JSON string from a db. I set the id of the pin (defined in a custom class) but I need to pass the ID to a action when pressing the detail disclosure button.

It will then open a new view with some information on that pin (via a database and it will lookup the row id and return the data, not sure how im going to do that just yet)

This is the code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [spinner stopAnimating];

    // json parsing
    results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    CustomAnnotation * myAnn;

    NSArray *pins = mapView.annotations;

    if ([pins count])
    {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:pins];
    }

    /* loop through the array, each key in the array has a JSON String with format:
     * title <- string
     * strap <- string
     * id <- int
     * date <- date
     * lat <- floating point double
     * long <- floating point double
     * link <- string

     */
    int i;


    for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
        //NSLog(@"Result: %i = %@", i, results[i]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"]);

        myAnn = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
        location.latitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
        myAnn.coordinate = location;
        myAnn.title = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
        myAnn.subtitle = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"strap"];
        myAnn.pinId = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];

        NSLog(@"id: %i", myAnn.pinId);

        [locations addObject:myAnn];

        //NSLog(@"%i", [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"]);
    }


    [self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    static NSString *s = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:s];
    if (!pin) {
        pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:s];
        pin.canShowCallout = YES;
        //pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];

        pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(viewDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

    }
    return pin;
}

-(void)viewDetails{

    NSLog(@"press");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

seems to me that you wish to detect which annotation is selected or its accessory view is clicked.

use the following method

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

available to detect the callout tap action. But rather than setting the tag of button, tag the mkannotationView which you will provide for display of you annotation

```
-(MKAnnotationView*) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Some of the best tutorials are 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this, I appriciate it. Does the first method replace the viewForAnnotation method in my above code? Thanks for the link I will take a look at the project there - looks like a great website!!

Comment: If you talking about the first method in my post, then it doesn't replace viewforannotation. viewForAnnotation is for different purpose and calloutAccessoryControlTapped is to detect the accessory control, on the callout of you mkannotationview, which appears when you click on the annotatation itself. Please go through the link suggest, will surely help you to understand the logic of MKMapView and its delegates and usage better.